# Seeding with Entity Framwork 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am a noob at ASP.NET MVC. In my application I have an entity called `Products`. I used a code-first approach and Entity Framework fluent api for mapping.

Here is my context class and want to know how I can do seeding for this context class. Thank you.

```
public class SimpleContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public SimpleContext() : base("name = DefaultDbContext")
    {
    }

    static SimpleContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SimpleContext>()); 
    }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typeToRegister =
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace)).Where(
                type =>
                type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
                type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
        foreach (var type in typeToRegister)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your intention with the `OnModelCreating` and `Set<TEntity>`? What you're doing is a little abnormal. Most people just define their models and add `DbSet<Product>` as a property and create migrations.

Comment: Start with this https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: i don't want to use DbSet<T>  because for every  of my entity  i need  to add DbSet<T> in my context class :( . @Cameron

Comment: @Nayeem In that case, I'm not sure how to help. But you'll want to double check that your `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is working the way that you intend.

Comment: This context class is irrelevant to your question. Seeding is done in a [db initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx).